# Is there an API using C# to change Windows 10 Active Hours?

Tags: c#, windows, api, auto-update

I lost a bunch of work last night again because Window's update restarted my computer during my 6 hour window that I can't make active.  I was simply too tired and forgot to change the active hours before I went to bed.

I want to write a C# application that changes my active hours automatically based on the current time.  That way the 6 hour window will never be active thereby effectively disabling automatic restart for windows updates.

However, I cannot find an API that lets me do it.  Can someone please point me in the correct direction?

Thanks.

Comment: another option might be to move the active hours setting in the registry programmatically. The settings is in registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsUpdate\UX\Settings. You'd have to check whether this setting is evaluated right before a reboot or only once after installing an update.

Comment: What do you mean you lost a ton of work? Windows rebooting whenever it wants to is annoying, but shouldn't result in loss of work. Are you saving your changes often? I don't feel comfortable leaving my computer without saving + committing to source control + pushing to remote server.

Comment: mason - I am running processes that translate data from DynamoDB to RedShift DB for 1 month at a time.  Depending on the data, it can take 16-24 hours.  When Windows shuts down, it kills these processes.  I need to remove all the month's data from RedShift and start all over again.

Comment: mason - even worse some of my machines host VMs and summarily closing them has corrupted them in the past.  I just have to stop this asinine behaviour that MS forced on us all.